# Problemas ao inserir valores em ponteiro de vetor

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, array

Estou com problemas ao tentar realizar um exercício de programação que me foi passado, onde se pede para "criar uma variável ponteiro do tipo vetor com 20 ocorrências do tipo caracteres".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
char *v[20];

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
char c;
v[i] = &c;
scanf("%c", &c);
*v[i] = c;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%c ", *v[i]);
}

getch();
}
```

Não dá nenhum erro ao compilar, mas há alguns problemas:
Ele sai do primeiro for não após digitar os 20 caracteres, **mas apenas 10 deles**;
O resultado do printf é um monte de espaços vazios

Minha experiência com ponteiros é quase nula, perguntei a alguns amigos que entendem mais, mas não consegui uma solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que o seu código deveria ser isso:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    char v[20];

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        char c;
        scanf("%c", &c);
        v[i] = c;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%c ", v[i]);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Testei aqui e funcionou. Apenas tive que retirar o `#include <conio.h>` e coloquei um `return 0;` no lugar do `getch();`.

Lembre-se que em C todo vetor é um ponteiro, então `char v[20];` é um ponteiro para um caractere. Ocorre apenas que este ponteiro aponta para uma área de memória já alocada na pilha de execução (stack) para 20 caracteres.

Já `char *v[20];` é um ponteiro para um outro ponteiro de caractere, que aponta para uma área de memória no stack aonde cabem 20 outros ponteiros. Não é isso que você quer!

O código `v[i] = &c;` é particularmente perigoso. Você pega o endereço de memória da variável `c` e coloca ela no vetor de caractere. Essa operação não tem sentido nenhum, além disso o tamanho do endereço de memória não cabe na posição do vetor, então o valor resultante vai ser truncado. O resultado será que você está poluindo o seu vetor com lixo.

Já `*v[i] = c;` significa que você pega o i-ésimo caractere de `v`, o interpreta como um ponteiro e o desreferencia, e coloca o valor do `c` na posição de memória resultante. Não é isso que você quer, você não quer interpretar o i-ésimo caractere como se fosse um ponteiro. O mais provável é que isso cause uma falha de segmentação no programa ou alguma outra coisa desastrosa.

Agora, olhando no código que eu corrigi, observe que você quase não precisa desreferenciar ponteiros explícitos, basta trabalhar com arrays. O único detalhe é o `scanf`, aonde você pega o endereço do `c` apenas.

Um outro detalhe do seu código: Ele sempre tentará ler os 20 caracteres, mesmo se o que você quiser digitar for menor que isso. Para resolver esse detalhe, caso você queira, você vai ter que verificar se o usuário digitou `\n` e parar.

Comment: Então, é que o enunciado do exercicio é o seguinte: "Crie uma variável ponteiro do tipo vetor com 20 ocorrências do tipo caracteres. Carregue este vetor realizando a leitura destas ocorrências e armazene-o na memória." Então eu pensei que precisaria fazer o vetor como um ponteiro em si... Mas uma coisa ainda está acontecendo mesmo com o seu código, ele só le metade dos caracteres que deveria, se eu coloco 20 no for, ele lê 10, se eu coloco 10, ele lê 5, tem alguma idéia do porque?

Comment: @Tryedz "Crie uma variável ponteiro do tipo vetor", isto é exatamente o que o `char v[20];` é. Ele é uma variável ponteiro e o tipo dele é um vetor. Se a ideia é utilizar um `char*` então o enunciado está mal-escrito, mas isso é fácil de arrumar. Quanto a este negócio de só ler a metade, você está digitando ENTER após cada caractere? Ele considera o ENTER um caractere como outro qualquer.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz algumas mudanças no seu código, não sei se atinge exatamente o objetivo, mas acredito que pode ajudar.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *v;
    char c[20];
    int i;  
    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &c[i]);
        getchar();

    }
    v = c;

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            printf("letra  i = %c \n", *(v+i));
    }

return 0;
}
```

Utilizei um ponteiro v apontando pra um vetor de char.
O `getchar()` dentro do `for` está pegando o enter que é dado. Esse é o motivo que o seu programa estava pegando apenas metade dos elementos, a outra metade era pego como enter.

No último `for`, trata-se de aritmética de ponteiro, `v` aponta pra o primeiro elemento de `c`, ou seja `c[0]`, então quando você faz `*(v+i)` está dizendo que vai acessar o endereço de `v` + o endereço de `i`. `i` não é um valor específico, é uma unidade do tipo de dado que `v` aponta, ou seja, `char`, então se `i = 1`,  `v+i == c[1]` pois está adicionando uma unidade de char no endereço de `v`.

Espero ter ajudado!